# How can I find MAX and MIN value and then copy and insert none duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider there is three tables Product Classification (PROD_CLASS), Document Header (DOC_H) and Document Body (DOC_B) with next schema

```
   PROD_CLASS         DOC_H           DOC_B
CODE char(10) PK     DATE date        CODE_FK   FK related to PROD_CLASS PK
NAME char(60)        NUMBER int PK    QUANTITY
P_TYPE char(10)      TYPE int         PRICE
                                      P_TYPE
                                      NUMBER_FK  FK related to DOC_H
```

How can I copy and insert none duplicate rows (none duplicate by Product Name (PROD_CLASS column Name)) from DOC_B to the DOC_B for the document with MAX number (column from DOC_H table) into document with MIN number (column from DOC_H table).

I have a very bad English, so I will try to describe my question on the example:

I have next table data:

```
PROD_CLASS
CODE   NAME  P_TYPE
1      Beer  Light
2      Milk  Low-fat
3      Bread Boule

DOC_H
DATE         NUMBER   TYPE
01/01/2012     1        1
01/02/2012     2        1
01/03/2012     3        1

DOC_B
CODE_FK   QUANTITY PRICE P_TYPE  NUMBER_FK
1           100      5     Light     1
3           200      3     Boule     1
1           50       6     Light     2
1           25       5     Light     3
2           100      10    Low-fat   3
3           100      3     Boule     3
```

The document with MAX number is #3 and document with MIN number is #1. I need to copy all products (rows) that are distinct by name from document #3 (doc with MAX number) to document #1 (doc with MIN number).

Comment: should be able to answer your own problem if you dissect what's required and make them one.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you don't want an entry in table 'doc_b' that has a duplicated entry in terms of pointing at the same Prod_Class & Doc_H as another entry in 'doc_b'.  If this is the case, you can do it be creating a unique index on code_fk and number_fk in the doc_b table.

> Create unique index ux_doc_b_code_fk_number_fk on DOC_B (code_fk, number_fk)